# SAS not running code

Tags: sas

Beginner SAS user here. I'm not quite sure what I've done but for whatever reason none of my code is running anymore. What I mean by this is when I press submit code/F8, nothing happens, and my log just shows what I submitted (it is basically a copy of my code). This is the case whether I try to run an entire program or just a piece of it.

It doesn't seem to be code specific. I've pulled up old code that I know has ran in the past, and the behavior is exactly the same. I'm wondering if I've triggered some kind of setting somewhere...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to clarify if this is in Base SAS or Enterprise Guide.

Comment: True - EG will automatically execute a "non-error producing" version of the magic quote below..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have unbalanced quotation marks.. (or something else is awry, eg missing `%mend;` statement or end bracket).  If starting a new session is not an option, try running the following:

```
;*';*";*/;)))%mend;quit;
```